# If you disconnect/get kicked do you still get points for the round?

Tags: battlefield-4

If you disconnect/get kicked do you still get points for the round?

The flaky nature of some of the servers is annoying; I rack up kills and points - but are they saved if the server crashes or I get kicked for idle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the server finishes the round, you will receive a battle report and the points you accumulated.

Now, if the server crashes, I believe the points and progress are lost.

Comment: What happens when you rejoin the server before the round is over? I'm not sure, but I think you lose the points (and unlocks) from previous plays in that round.

Comment: That's a good question I don't know the answer to.

Comment: After checking seems to be if you get kicked or lose connection as long as the server is up; points are saved.
If you rejoin, you're reset to zero - pants!

Answer (score 0):

You still get all of the unlocks and points. It just takes about two minutes until you can see your unlocks in the battlelog.